# How to analyze why a classic ASP page with 1 word in it takes 10 seconds to display on our website?

Tags: iis, webserver, windows-server-2012-r2

Our classic ASP (not ASP.NET) website is taking 10 seconds to initial display and we're trying to make a case to our web host that it is something in their settings that is causing this delay. As a test, we created a test ASP page with just the word "hello" in it, called hello.asp. When visiting that page, it also takes up to 10 seconds to display.
We also created a simple HTM file with 1 word in it called hello.htm. When we visit that page, it runs instantly, leading us to believe that the problem is with the web server's handling of ASP pages. But we don't know what settings to advise the web host to inspect. We just provided a link to both hello.asp and hello.htm pages so that they could see for themselves.
Here is the content of the ASP version of the page:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>hello
</body>
</html>
```

Any advice as to how we can direct the web host to target their investigation? They seem stumped.

Comment: Not sure why you chose the Windows Server 2012 R2 tag, but that version of Windows reached end of life so any issue (security or performance) is expected and you shouldn't expect anything there. If you can reproduce the same issue on a fully supported Windows release, you'd better open a support case with Microsoft to get assistance. I wonder how many outsiders still remember how to analyze ASP performance issues.

Comment: check if the server is running the latest compatible version. try enabling failed request tracing and set the rule to collect logs for delay response.  If possible, test the same pages on a different server with a similar configuration. This can help determine if the issue is specific to the current server or a more general issue with the ASP setup. could you share your asp setting snapshot

Comment: Going to have to see the IIS settings and web.config to be able to make that case.

Comment: If you want to really get down in there, use a timer function, example found here, then you can get the actual execution time.  If its VERY fast, its not the asp but something else, but if its the 10 seconds, the script is somehow hanging it that long, maybe due to a timeout? This info might help you find out if its the asp script or the IIS settings.  --> https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_timer.asp

Comment: Did you gather the timing information using the method I outlined, you can determine if its the script or other IIS issues ... I'm curious how long it took to execute.